# MongoEngine not checking/saving unique indexes upon save

Tags: python, django, mongodb, django-rest-framework, mongoengine

The problem I am having is when I save a new FAQ upon post with an identical tag, it saves, despite making the tag unique. I am new to django and python in general, so I am wondering if there is something wrong with my code or should I submit a bug to mongoengine or some other package.

Any Ideas?

Objective:

- Create a FAQ system with unique tags grouped by subjects with tags.
- Tags need to be unique.
- Full FAQ list should be able to be listed without being grouped by subject.
- FAQ List should be able to be listed by subject groups.

Libraries:

- Python 3.4
- Django 1.7
- Django Rest Framework 2.4
- Mongo Engine 8.7
- PyMongo 2.7.2
- Django Rest Framework Mmongoengine 1.5.3

Models:

```
class Faq(Document):
    question = StringField(db_field='faq', required=True, unique=True)
    tag = StringField()
    answers = StringField()

class Section(Document):
    section = StringField(db_field='section', required=True)
    tag = StringField(db_field='tag', required=True, unique=True)
    faqs = ListField(ReferenceField('Faq'))
```

Serializers:

```
class FaqSerializer(serializers.MongoEngineModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Faq


class SectionSerializer(serializers.MongoEngineModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Section
```

Views:

```
class SectionDetail(APIView):
    def post(self, request, format=None):
        """
        Creates a single Section.
        """
        serializer = SectionSerializer(data=request.DATA)

        if serializer.is_valid() is False:
            return Response(
                data=serializer.errors,
                status=status.HTTP_500_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR
            )

        serializer.save()
        return Response(
            data=serializer.data,
            status=status.HTTP_200_OK
        )
```